# Php zipping only one file whereas two files are given

Tags: php, function, zip

I have a form that inputs two files one is eps file other is jpg file.

I put the paths of these two files in an array.

```
function create_zip($files = array(), $destination=""){

  if(count($files)){
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if($zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
      return false;
    }

    foreach($files as $file){
      $file_name = explode(".", $file);
      $check = count($file_name)-1;
      $name = "vector". "." . $file_name[$check];
      $zip->addFile($file,$name);
      //$zip->addFile($file,$name);
      echo "{$name}";
      //$zip->addFile($file,$file);
    }

    $zip->close();
    return file_exists($destination);
  }
}
```

This code creates zip file in the destination but the problem is that it only creates zip of eps. Jpg is not added in the zip.

This is how I call this function

```
$files = array($target_path_jpg,$target_path);
create_zip($files, "../download/{$name}.zip");
```

There is no problem with paths.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define `$target_path_jpg` and `$target_path`?

Comment: These are absolute paths to the two files

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\image_2016-12-03-12-25-25_5842aba5762675.eps and the other is C:\xampp\htdocs\photo_gallery\public\images\image_2016-12-03-12-25-25_5842aba5762675.jpg one of the file is archived but the other one fails. Is there is any limit that it only adds one file that needs to be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it gives no error whether file exists or not. So there was no file at that time it was created after that